# Push values to the same index of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, key

I wish to add key/value pairs into the same index of an array inside a loop.

Something Like this:

```
$attributes = array();
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
    {
        array_push($attributes, array("title" => "this is content" . $i));
    }
```

except that the above would add new arrays to the original one. The output of above would be:

```
[{"title":"this is content0"},{"title":"this is content1"},{"title":"this is content2"}]
```

What I need is something like the following:

```
{"title1":"Hello World!","title2":"yoyoyyooyy"}
```

So the array still has a single index but multiple key/value pairs in that index separated by a comma.

Please HELP!!!

Comment: So you are saying you want the value of  $attributes[n] to be be a serialized object rather than an array?  I would create the object then json_encode the whole thing and store the encoded object in $attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$attributes = array();
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
    {
        $attributes["title".$i]= "this is content".$i;
    }
```

this will help you no need to use array push

Comment: Thank you this is a very simple solution. Can't realise I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

```
$attributes = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
      $attributes['title'][] = "content".$i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at all what do you want to achieve...

> *So the array still has a single index but multiple key/value pairs in that index separated by a comma.*

Taking it literally would you want something like this? (that would be *serializing*)

```
$attributes:
    array(1) {
      [0]=> "Title1,This is content0,Title2,This is content1,Title3, (...)"
      string(n)
```

Because if so, you'd just need to do this:

```
$index_values = array();
for ($i=0; $i<N; $i++)
{
     $index_values[] = "Title" . $i;
     $index_values[] = "This is content". $i;
}
```

then

```
$attributes[0] = implode(",", $index_values);
```

Alternatively, you could do what other fellow users told above, then `json_encode($array)` that resulting array into first index of destination array.

**Note**: as far as I know, you can't have spare key/pair values without being encapsulated inside an structure like an array or an object.